# Making sense of RFC2616 and proxy servers

Tags: http, server, http-proxy, request-headers, rfc2616

Could someone help me distill down what, exactly, the minimum requirements are for a proxy server (just a forward proxy not reverse) with regard to headers? What headers absolutely must be deleted from the client request before it's passed upstream by the proxy server?

I'm trying to make sense of the [rfc2616 doc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) but it's slightly impenetrable to me and I've yet to find any blogs or articles that just isolate what the requirements or expectations are for a proxy server with regard to headers.